# How to install wordpress with postgresql

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I m newbie in wordpress. i just install wordpress 4.2.2. I want to install wordpress on heroku with postgresql. Before that i try to install wordpress with postgresql on my localhost. I follow the [PG4WP installation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/) steps but still my wordpress install with mysql database its not giving me option to install with postgresql.

I am using `Wordpress 4.2.2` version and for database i am using `postgresql 9.1`

Answer (score 27):

It might be a little late, but the current answers are and were wrong. It is possible to use PostgreSQL, even though it is not officially supported and it is not recommend for various reasons: The official documentation says, that it would be expensive to realize since every new wordpress version would have to be tested against the other database back-ends and since many plugins also rely on mysql-specific calls it will probably never be possible to make 'everything' multi database compatible. Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases

If you still want to use wordpress with PostgreSQL the better place to start would be the official PostgreSQL documentation. It says, that one needs a wordpress plugin called 'PG4WP' to make it work. 
Source: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Wordpress

Comment: There is currently nothing in the postgresql wiki except two links which are already in the question resp. in the first part of this answer. The PG2WP plugin appears to be outdated.

Comment: A more recent plugin based on the one OP linked can be found at https://wordpress.org/plugins/wppg/

Comment: In other words, there's no alternative DB support, because the WP core devs don't know how to do CI.

Answer (score 3):

Tutorial:
https://medium.com/@shoaibhassan_/install-wordpress-with-postgresql-using-apache-in-5-min-a26078d496fb

Repo used in tutorial:
https://github.com/kevinoid/postgresql-for-wordpress

```
=== PostgreSQL for WordPress (PG4WP) ===
Contributors: Hawk__ (http://www.hawkix.net/)
Requires at least: 2.9.2
Tested up to: 4.5.3
Stable tag: 1.3.1
License: GPLv2 or later

PostgreSQL for WordPress is a special 'plugin' enabling WordPress to be used with a PostgreSQL database.
```