# MySQL not using index to sort on and select a value from an indexed column

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

### The Table

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

```
CREATE TABLE wp_terms (
    term_id    bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment,
    name       varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    slug       varchar(200),
    term_group bigint(10) DEFAULT 0,

    PRIMARY KEY ( term_id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

### The Index

```mysql
MySQL> show index from wp_terms;
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| wp_terms |          1 | name     |            1 | name        | A         |      716638 |      191 |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

### The Query

```mysql
MySQL> select name from wp_terms order by name limit 1;
+--------------------+
| name               |
+--------------------+
|  ****************  |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.83 sec)
```

### The `Explain`

```mysql
MySQL> explain select name from wp_terms order by name limit 1;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_terms | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 802726 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
```

### The Question

Why isn't the 'name' index even a possible key? Forcing it had no effect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the **exact** column-type specification of `wp_terms.name`? (including `NULL` / `NOT NULL`)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And what storage-engine are you using for the `wp_terms` table?

Comment: I have no explanation: Large table, index on `name`, with high cardinality should mean the index is being used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I noticed the index's `sub_part` is `191` (and not `NULL`), which means the column is only partially indexed, could that be why?

Comment: @Dai 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.1
innodb

Comment: `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

Comment: @Dai Good catch, I'll bet you're right.  So continuing with your reading, the cardinality stat is not accurate, because maybe the _prefix indexed_ has low cardinality, and hence MySQL would rather just scan.

Comment: This comment doesn't affect the current question, but for the future, please identify that you're using AWS Aurora. Aurora has changed a significant amount of code from MySQL, and not all answers pertaining to MySQL will be accurate for Aurora.

Comment: Will do, @BillKarwin

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Dai for pointing out the issue. 'name' was an index prefix, not a full index. Creating a full index on name resulted in index being used for the query.

```mysql
MySQL> alter table wp_terms add index(name);
MySQL> explain select name from wp_terms order by name limit 1;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_terms | NULL       | index | NULL          | name_2 | 802     | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you create the prefix-index in the first place?

Comment: @Dai I inherited the DB... just working on optimizing it.

Comment: Working on a heavily-customized WordPress install? You have my sympathy.

Comment: Haha, thanks! Getting it done though. Amazing what can be achieved with a few well targeted indexes! This one had me stumped though. TIL about index prefixes!

Comment: I avoid MySQL as much as I can, so pardon my ignorance, but just what is an index-prefix? (I honestly don't know, I used this QA as an opportunity to read-up on what `EXPLAIN` reports, my (upvoted) comments were from just reading the docs) - I don't think I've ever come across anything similar in any other RDBMS.

Comment: It is an index built from first N characters of the column. I guess that's useful IF you wanted an index on a giant BLOB or something... Still i should be questioning my life choices if i was contemplating that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-prefix

Comment: Huh? that's it? that seems like it would have a very limited number of use-cases - still, [why not just run WordPress on Postgres instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347508/how-to-install-wordpress-with-postgresql)?

Comment: @Dai WordPress has never supported PostgreSQL (or any database besides MySQL or its clones).

Comment: @BillKarwin Not officially, no - but it's still possible to make it work in certain (limited, unsupported) situations

Comment: @Dai On cheap WP hosting sites? I doubt it.